# How to remove quotes from strings in an array?

Tags: ruby, escaping

Assuming I have the following input:

```
names = ["\"Петр Сергеевич\"", "\"Курсатов Роман\"", "\" \"", "\"Павел2 Олегович\"", "\"Илья иванович\"", "\" \""]
```

Each whitespace is actually a non-breaking space (U+00A0).

How do I remove `\"` in pure ruby, so the following is true:

```
p names
=> ["Петр Сергеевич", "Курсатов Роман", " ", "Павел2 Олегович", "Илья иванович", " "]
```

I tried:

```
names.map { |i| i.gsub(/[\"]/, "")}.map(&:inspect)
names.map { |i| i.delete('\\"')}.map(&:inspect)
names.map { |i| i.gsub('\\"', '')}.map(&:inspect)
```

Nothing seems to work.

Comment: The character `\ ` is actually not present in the string. But since `"" ""` is not grammatical, the quotes inside the string are "escaped" when the string gets surrounded by double quotes in its representation. `string.gsub('"', '')` or `string.gsub("\"", "")` or `string.gsub(/"/, '')` is fine.

Comment: @Amadan, thanks, it works in console, but not with the actual code. i have no idea what's happening

Comment: To simply remove one or more characters from a string, use [`delete`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.2/String.html#method-i-delete).

Comment: What do you mean by "whitespace is actually `&nbsp;`"? Do you mean that `string` is actually `"\"&nbsp;\""`?

Comment: @icherevkov _"it works in console, but not with the actual code"_ – what _is_ your actual code?

Comment: @sawa, no, it looks like whitespace, but it's actually ASCII symbol (code 160).

Comment: @Stefan, i updated the question

Comment: `names.map { |name| name.delete('"') }` works for me just fine for your example data.

Comment: @Stefan `names.map { |name| name.delete('"') }.map(&:inspect)` shows characters are still there

Comment: @icherevkov because you added `.map(&:inspect)`

Comment: @Stefan Looks like I was overcomplicating

Comment: So it means that you want to remove quotes which are **inside** of the strings too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string.delete("\"")
# => " "
```

or

```
string.tr("\"", "")
# => " "
```